# Why when i add a new product in my local storage, he is replace by the new one

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I don't understand in my code why when I click on my productBtn, my item in the local storage is replaced by the new one

```
buttonProduct = document.getElementById('productBtn');
  buttonProduct.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const storageCameras = localStorage.getItem('basketCameras') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basketCameras')) : [];
    storageCameras.push(product._id)
    localStorage.setItem('basketCameras', JSON.stringify([product._id]));
  })
}
```

because in my code, I get an element, then I push, and finally, I set

is it because every time I click on `productBtn` I refresh my []?

I just want to add and display all my elements ( i got 5 items)

Comment: why are you setting to storage JSON.stringify([product._id])) in stead of storageCameras

Comment: You are not using the `storageCameras` variable

Comment: Small little side note trick; `const storageCameras = JSON.parse(localStorage.get('basketCameras') || '[]');` can get rid of your ternary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use  storageCameras variable

```
buttonProduct = document.getElementById('productBtn');

  buttonProduct.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const storageCameras = localStorage.getItem('basketCameras') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('basketCameras')) : [];
    storageCameras.push(product._id)
    localStorage.setItem('basketCameras', JSON.stringify(storageCameras));
  })
}
```